# C# programatically remotely connect to Linux server to connect to Amazon RDS DB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have an executable in C# that needs to remotely connect to a Linux server in order to connect to an Amazon RDS database.

The executable lives on a Windows Server. Only the Linux server is able to connect to the RDS database due to permissions. Since the C# executable needs information from the database, I have found myself needing to first connect to the Linux server, and then from there connect to the database.

```
// include files
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Renci.SshNet;    
//...
     using (var client = new SshClient("server.amazonaws.com", "serverUser", privateKeyFile))
     {
            client.Connect();

            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = null;
            string connString = "Server=dbServer.rds.amazonaws.com; database=database " +             
                                "UID=databaseUser password=databasePassword";
            databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            databaseConnection.Open();

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_table;"; // errors here


           // ..... }
```

I get an error when assigning the querystring that says "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect any of the specified MySQL hosts.'"

I'm using [SSH.Net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) to form the connection to the Linux server. I'm using [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to connect and retrieve information from the database.

If there's something wrong with my code, I'd greatly appreciate it being pointed out, however I'm fairly certain I'm missing some necessary step to properly connect to the database. I noticed other questions asking something similar, but they either haven't been using an RDS DB or didn't have to SSH in through C#.

**EDIT:** Since posting this, the server I am executing this code on has been given access to the RDS database. I currently do not have time to attempt the solutions posted. What I can say is that after being given access, things are working smoothly only using MySql Connector.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do. Opening an ssh session to a machine then trying to open a sql connection from the windows machine is not doing anything. You could use the ssh session to execute a sql command line action. Or you need to have a service on the linux box that you can talk to that will forward the request.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a big mess. The C# executable needs information from the database as it uses SqlDataReader objects to grab the row information for some methods. I am not opposed to having a service on the Linux box, but then I don't see myself being able to use those objects. I inherited this project and have limited time, so I don't want to try to change all of the assignments from using that object versus using something else.
Would using the SSH session to execute the SQL command line action still allow me to do this? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: This is bad design. You should create a web application on the Linux machine that exposes an API, then use that API from the Windows machine to access the database. You are opening yourself up to all kinds of security issues.

Comment: I agree, I actually suggested something similar, but this isn't entirely up to me. For the sake of the question, I'd really appreciate help within these constraints.

Comment: What you want to do can't be done. The problem with your code is that the AWS service allows connections to the database only from the Linux machine. You are trying to initiate a connection from the Windows machine. The only way to do this is to create some kind of API between the Linux machine and the Windows machine or else you need to log in to your AWS account and grant database access to your Windows machine.

Comment: @Icemanind Thanks for the answer. I take it that just because I'm connecting via SSH.NET, it's not enough to then connect to the database. I'd suggest putting this as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the SSH.  On your Linux box, configure IPtables to port-forward to AWS.  Pick any arbitrary port number, say 12345.

Any incoming TCP connections to port 12345 will forward traffic to a given host name and port on AWS.

Subsequently, your MySQL connection string will connect to port 12345 on your linux box, but the forward will send the traffic to AWS.

Here are some sample articles:

- [Port Redirection Example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/)
- [How can I port forward with IPTables?](http://How%20can%20I%20port%20forward%20with%20iptables?)
- [How To Forward Ports through a Linux Gateway with Iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)

As IPtables can be a pain in the rear to configure manually, consider installing [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) first as an easy-to-use web interface to configure iptables with.

Comment: The security of this solution is pretty weak. Anyone with a MySQL client could brute-force attack the server using username/password guesses. Using SSH is far more secure.

Comment: @MattHouser Moot point, considering the fact that RDS endpoints are public.

Comment: RDS endpoints can be public if you want. They can also be 100% private and only accessible from inside your VPC.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. I'm not familiar with SSH.NET, but when using Putty (an SSH terminal), you would configure SSH "port tunneling" or "port forwarding" which will setup a listening port on your local computer. Any connections to your local port are forwarded along the SSH connection to the remote computer, then forwarded on to the final destination.

https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET does mention that it supports "port forwarding". Take a look at using that.

1. Connect to your Linux box using SSH.NET
2. Configure a port forward from localhost:12345 to dbServer.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
3. Use `localhost:12345` in your connection string as the target server rather than `dbServer.rds.amazonaws.com:3306` for `MySqlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting through SSH is not enoguh. What you want to do can't be done. The problem with your code is that the AWS service allows connections to the database only from the Linux machine. You are trying to initiate a connection from the Windows machine. The only way to do this is to create some kind of API between the Linux machine and the Windows machine or else you need to log in to your AWS account and grant database access to your Windows machine